# Check if dates and times overlap for two separate data frames in R

Tags: r

In a data frame containing traffic jams, start date, end date, start time, end time, road, direction (right or left), start road section and end road section are provided. An example looks like this:

```
start date    end date    start time    end time    road    direction   start road section    end road section
2015-03-02    2015-03-02     07:29        09:45      A1        R               113.1               125.7
2017-05-04    2017-05-05     23:29        01:45      A10       L               12.5                14.3
```

Another large dataframe (20+ million rows) contains all possible combinations of road sections (divided into pieces of 20 kms) and times (divided into hours) from 2015 until 2020. An example looks like this:

```
date         time         road      direction      road section
2015-03-02  09:00-10:00   A1          R               100 - 120
2015-03-02  10:00-11:00   A1          R               100 - 120
2015-03-02  09:00-10:00   A1          R               80 - 100
```

I would like to add a binary variable to the second data frame indicating whether or not there was a traffic jam at that moment on that certain road section. In this example, the first row would take the value 1 as both time and road section range overlap with the traffic jam in the first row of the first data frame. The second and third row, however, will take the value 0, as either time or road section do not overlap.

Any help and/or suggestions is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this was a pretty tall task whose solution involved *quite* some work. In the end, it was a nice Sunday afternoon exercise. Let's hope it works with your full dataset.

**Data**

```
ex <- data.frame(start_date = c("2015-03-02", "2017-05-04"),
                 end_date = c("2015-03-02", "2017-05-05"), 
                 start_time = c("07:29", "23:29"), 
                 end_time = c("09:45", "01:45"), 
                 road = c("A1", "A10"), 
                 direction = c("R", "L"),
                 start_road_section = c(113.1, 12.5), 
                 end_road_section = c(125.7, 14.3)) 
df <- data.frame(date = c("2015-03-02", "2015-03-02", "2015-03-02"),
                 time = c("09:00-10:00", "10:00-11:00", "09:00-10:00"),
                 road = c("A1", "A1", "A1"), 
                 direction = c("R", "R", "R"), 
                 road_section = c("100 - 120", "100 - 120", "80 - 100"))
```

**1st step: Cleaning the data**

```
df %<>% mutate(time_component = strsplit(as.character(time), "-")) %>% 
               tidyr::unnest_wider(time_component, names_sep = "_")   %>%        
                     select(-time) %>% 
                         mutate(road_component = strsplit(as.character(road_section), " - ")) %>% 
                           tidyr::unnest_wider(road_component, names_sep = "_") %>% 
                                   select(-road_section)
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  date       road  direction time_component_1 time_component_2 road_component_1 road_component_2
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>     <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 2015-03-02 A1    R         09:00            10:00            100              120             
2 2015-03-02 A1    R         10:00            11:00            100              120             
3 2015-03-02 A1    R         09:00            10:00            80               100
```

**2nd step: Combining the data**

```
comb_df <- dplyr::inner_join(ex,df, by=c("start_date" = "date", "road", "direction"))
comb_df$start_road_section <- as.numeric(comb_df$start_road_section) 
comb_df$end_road_section <- as.numeric(comb_df$end_road_section) 
comb_df$road_component_1 <- as.numeric(comb_df$road_component_1) 
comb_df$road_component_2 <- as.numeric(comb_df$road_component_2)
```

**3rd step: Finding the overlap in time and road section**

```
new_df <- comb_df %>% mutate(ex_start = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(start_date, start_time, sep = " ")),
                    ex_end = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(end_date, end_time, sep = " ")), 
                    df_start = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(start_date, time_component_1, sep = " ")),
                    df_end = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(start_date, time_component_2, sep = " ")),
                    Intervall_ex = lubridate::interval(start = ex_start, end = ex_end),
                    Intervall_df = lubridate::interval(start = df_start, end = df_end), 
                    Time_Contained = ifelse(int_overlaps(Intervall_ex, Intervall_df), 1, 0), 
                    Road_Contained = ifelse(((start_road_section < road_component_1) & (end_road_section > road_component_1)) | 
                                              ((start_road_section > road_component_1) & (start_road_section < road_component_2)), 
                                            1, 
                                            0), 
                    Final_Result = ifelse(Time_Contained + Road_Contained == 2, 1, 0))
```

**4th and final step: Reducing the dataset**

```
final_df <- new_df %>% select(start_date, end_date, road, 
                              direction, road_component_1, road_component_2, 
                              time_component_1, time_component_2, Final_Result)
> final_df
  start_date   end_date road direction road_component_1 road_component_2 time_component_1 time_component_2 Final_Result
1 2015-03-02 2015-03-02   A1         R              100              120            09:00            10:00            1
2 2015-03-02 2015-03-02   A1         R              100              120            10:00            11:00            0
3 2015-03-02 2015-03-02   A1         R               80              100            09:00            10:00            0
```

Comment: Thanks! In essence your suggested code works. However, because of the sheer size of the df data frame, I am running out of memory when running the 1st and 3rd step. Do you foresee any solutions for this problem. Off course, the other option is taking a subset of the data frame df.

Comment: Well, performance is a separate issue of course. There are several possibilities (e.g.  `data.table` solutions or parallel computing), but this is not easily done. As you wrote, another option is just subsetting the dataframe which seems easiest here.